# Trying to do two MySQL Calculation based on value of one column

Tags: mysql, case, calculated-columns

I have a select statement but want to evaluate one column, if it contains value of 584. I am trying to create a new calculation column called total by multiplying 3 other columns, if not 584 then calculate based on different columns

```
    select CASE `d2c_3_csg_batch_in`.`transactioncode` AS `transactioncode`,
`d2c_3_csg_batch_in`.`site` AS `site`,
`d2c_3_csg_employees`.`lastname` AS `lastname`,
`d2c_3_csg_employees`.`firstname` AS `firstname`,
`d2c_3_csg_employees`.`payrate` AS `payrate`,
`d2c_3_csg_batch_in`.`employeecode` AS `employeecode`,
`d2c_3_csg_batch_in`.`jobcode` AS `jobcode`,
`d2c_3_csg_employees`.`CompanyFrequency` AS `CompanyFrequency`,
`d2c_3_csg_batch_in`.`inputunits` AS `inputunits`,
`d2c_3_csg_transactioncodes`.`multiplier` AS `multiplier`,
`d2c_3_csg_transactioncodes`.`payspacewording` AS `payspacewording`,
        WHEN `d2c_3_csg_batch_in`.`transactioncode` = '584' THEN `d2c_3_csg_batch_in`.`inputunits` AS `total`
        WHEN `d2c_3_csg_batch_in`.`transactioncode` <> '584' THEN `d2c_3_csg_batch_in`.`inputunits` * `d2c_3_csg_employees`.`payrate` * `d2c_3_csg_transactioncodes`.`multiplier` AS `total` 
     END
from ((`d2c_3_csg_transactioncodes` join `d2c_3_csg_batch_in` on(`d2c_3_csg_transactioncodes`.`code` = `d2c_3_csg_batch_in`.`transactioncode`)) 
left join `d2c_3_csg_employees` on(`d2c_3_csg_batch_in`.`employeecode` = `d2c_3_csg_employees`.`employeenumber`)) 
where `d2c_3_csg_batch_in`.`flag` = 'ADD' and `d2c_3_csg_batch_in`.`prp` = 'Y' 
group by `d2c_3_csg_batch_in`.`employeecode`,`d2c_3_csg_batch_in`.`transactioncode` 
order by `d2c_3_csg_batch_in`.`employeecode` desc,`d2c_3_csg_batch_in`.`transactioncode`
```

Comment: Alias must be assigned to the whole column expression, not to `WHEN/ELSE` branches.

Comment: That is an invalid case statement see  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html case should appear immediateley before the first when clause..

Comment: tried adding the CASE statement on before the first WHEN statement but get error

Syntax error near 'AS `total` WHEN `d2c_3_csg_batch_in`.`transactioncode` <> '584' THEN...' at line 14

Comment: You also need to implement @akina comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Sum if
e.g

```
SUM(if (q1.bill = 584,q1.bill - q1.payment,0))AS bal,
SUM(if (q1.bill != 584,q1.payment - q1.bill  ,0))AS advpay,
```

q1 is table alias. other fields are imaginary

Point of correction: When using case, you do it this way;

```
CASE WHEN `d2c_3_csg_batch_in`.`transactioncode` = '584' 
         THEN `d2c_3_csg_batch_in`.`inputunits` 
     WHEN `d2c_3_csg_batch_in`.`transactioncode` <> '584' 
         THEN `d2c_3_csg_batch_in`.`inputunits` * `d2c_3_csg_employees`.`payrate` * `d2c_3_csg_transactioncodes`.`multiplier` 
END AS `total`    -- an alias must be there!
```

Comment: Thank you !!! both options worked... I first did this which worked 100% but then used your second suggestion

`sum(if(`d2c_3_csg_batch_in`.`transactioncode` = 584,`d2c_3_csg_batch_in`.`inputunits`,0)) + sum(if(`d2c_3_csg_batch_in`.`transactioncode` <> 584,`d2c_3_csg_batch_in`.`inputunits` * `d2c_3_csg_employees`.`payrate` * `d2c_3_csg_transactioncodes`.`multiplier`,0)) AS `total` `